# jmeter grab value from response data

Tags: regex, xpath, jmeter, beanshell, extractor

I have a question about grabbing a certain value from the html response data in Jmeter.
I've been trying both regular expression and xpath extractor(see below) but having no luck.

This is part of the response data I receive:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" style="border-collapse: collapse" id="AutoNumber2" bordercolorlight="#999999" bordercolordark="#999999" width="100%">
   <tr> 
      <td class="head" align="center" colspan="2">Routing Sheet</td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="altrow"> 
      <td align="right" width="50%" class="formtext">Today's Date:</td>
      <td valign="top" width="50%" class="formtext">06/19/2012</td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="altrow"> 
      <td align="right" width="50%" class="formtext"> HCSC Received Date:</td>
      <td valign="top" width="50%" class="formtext">06/19/2012</td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="tablerow"> 
      <td align="right" width="50%" class="formtext"> Package Log Date:</td>
      <td valign="top" width="50%" class="formtext">06/19/2012 04:21PM</td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="altrow"> 
      <td align="right" width="50%" class="formtext"> Group Specialist:</td>   
      <td valign="top" width="50%" class="formtext">WATTS, JOHN</td>            
   </tr>

   <tr class="tablerow"> 
      <td align="right" width="50%" class="formtext"> Case Underwriter:</td>
      <td valign="top" width="50%" class="formtext">N/A</td>           
   </tr>    

   <tr class="altrow"> 
       <td align="right" width="50%" class="formtext"> Medical Underwriter:</td>  
       <td valign="top" width="50%" class="formtext">N/A</td>    
   </tr>

   <tr class="tablerow"> 
       <td align="right" width="50%" class="formtext">Case Number:</td>                           
       <td valign="top" width="50%" class="formtext">7402628</td>
   </tr>
```

And I'm trying to grab the case number.
I have been trying the regex extractor:

```
Case Number:</td><td valign="top" width="50%" class="formtext">(.+?)</td>
```

But got a null value back.

And for xpath extractor I tried this:

```
//table[@id='AutoNumber2']/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]
```

but it's not working either.
I've been thinking of using Beanshell to grab the source code as a string and parse the number.
Is there any better way of grabbing that number?
And how can I use beanshell to grab the source code of the response data?
I tried using xpath of /html but have no luck.

Thanks a lot

Comment: One reason why your XPath expression doesn't select the wanted elements is because there is no `tbody` in the provided XML document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this xpath:

```
//table[@id='AutoNumber2']/tr[8]/td[2]
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this, I tested it on your sample and it works :

[image]

Let me know if that works for you

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are using [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) to parse HTML (not XML!..) response ensure that **Use Tidy (tolerant parser)** option is CHECKED.
2. Your xpath query should return value you want to extract.
   Refine your xpath query, e.g.

   `//table[@id='AutoNumber2']/tbody/tr[td/text()='Case Number:']/td[2]/text()`
3. To use Beanshell for parsing look into this: [Using jmeter variables in xpath extractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192884/using-jmeter-variables-in-xpath-extractor).
4. You can first test your xpath query using any other tool - Firefox addons at least:

   - [XPath Checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpath-checker/)
   - [XPather](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpather/)
   - [XPath Finder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpath-finder/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewResultsTree listener component to test and tweak your regex expression on your actual response data.

To find out what happens in runtime use Debug component.

At the first glance I see that it doesn't match because you're missing new line in your regex expression (following `Case Number:</td>`).

See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) for special characters that emulate new line.